# ListBox ItemTemplate Hit Test

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have the following ListBox with an ItemTemplate

```
<ListBox SelectionMode="Multiple" ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}" DisplayMemberPath="Name">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}">
                <ContentControl VerticalAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Content="{Binding}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

This displays all well and good, but the hit test on the ContentControl isn't right...if I click above or below the "actual" content (if the item has more Height than the ContentControl, then the item isn't selected.

If I change the ControlControl VerticalAlignment to Stretch, that resolves the problem and all clicks correctly highlight items...but then my Content is top-aligned within each item...

How can I get items to select correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the `Grid` hit-test for example

```
<Grid Background="Transparent" ...>
```

Comment: bingo....I had already tried setting IsHitTestVisible="True", but that didn't work...any idea why?

Comment: That property is just an override as far as i know, meaning that if you set it to `false` and there is "something" it will ignore that something, however if there is nothing to begin with then having it on `true` (the default) won't do anything. By having a background you create "something" to hit-test.